# Hiding one control and showing another when user makes a choice in MVC5 and EF6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

In my MVC5 controller, I am filling two lists in my ViewModel like so:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
        {
            var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var model = new RegisterViewModel()
            {                    
                RegionsList = db.Regions.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Selected = false,
                    Text = x.Name,
                    Value = x.Name
                }),
                CompanyList = db.Companies.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Selected = false,
                    Text = x.Name,
                    Value = x.CompanyId.ToString()
                })
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

Then, in my View, I show the Companies as a DropDownList and the Regions as a group of check boxes:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyList, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedCompanyId, Model.CompanyList, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Assign the user to one or more regions", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <span class=" col-md-10">
                @foreach (var item in Model.RegionsList)
                {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRegionNames" value="@item.Value" checked="@item.Selected" class="checkbox-inline" />
                    @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
                }
            </span>
        </div>
```

This works OK, except that it is a bit messy since all regions for all companies are shown. I would like to hide the group of checkboxes until a company is picked, and then hide the company dropdownlist and show a list of regions where region.CompanyId == the one selected.

Can anyone educate me on how to do that please?

Comment: If you're just showing/hiding things as part of the UI in the browser then I would recommend doing this with JavaScript instead of server-side code.  Basically, render everything to the page as you have now and style it as not visible by default.  As the user interacts with page elements, show the elements that should be shown.

Comment: I don't think I am just showing/hiding as the contents of RegionList needs to change based on what is selected from CompanyList.

Comment: Is it going to post back to the server and re-render the page, then?  If that's the case then I imagine your view can just bind to filtered lists on the model instead of the whole lists.  If the filter criteria is available on the model, maybe just create read-only properties which filter the lists based on those criteria?

Comment: How do I get it to rerender when the company selection changes?

Comment: If the processing is done server-side then it would require a trip to the server.  Either wrap the elements in a form and post that form when the selection changes (use JavaScript to listen to the `select`'s change event and invoke the form submit) or make an AJAX request when the selection changes (use JavaScript to listen to the `select`'s change event and make the AJAX request).

Comment: Can you make an answer instead of a comment and show me how to do the AJAX in this limited/specific case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the filtering server-side, then your order of operations might look something like this:

- Display all companies, but no regions
- Respond to change event for the companies form element
- Get the associated regions from an AJAX call
- Create your region selections

In the first step, all you'd be doing is no longer showing any regions.  So you don't need them in the view model:

```
var model = new RegisterViewModel()
{                    
    CompanyList = db.Companies.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Selected = false,
        Text = x.Name,
        Value = x.CompanyId.ToString()
    })
};
return View(model);
```

But you will need a way to identify the HTML element which will contain them client-side.  An `id` value works well for that:

```
<span id="regionsSelection" class="col-md-10"></span>
```

In the second step, you'd attach a `change` handler to the `select` element that has the companies.  You'll need a way to identify that element, of course.  For example, if it's `name` attribute is `SelectedCompanyId` then this should work:

```
$('select[name="SelectedCompanyId"]').change(function () {

});
```

The third step will involve making the AJAX call inside of that `change` handler.  But before we can do that we'll need a server-side controller action to get the regions based on a selected company.  I'm mostly guessing on your object model details, but the structure would be something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetRegions(int companyId)
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var regions = db.Regions.Where(r => r.Companies.Any(c => c.Id == companyId));
    return Json(regions);
}
```

The idea there is to fetch the regions associated with the provided company ID and return them as a JSON array.  Then you can call that action from client-side code in the `change` handler.  Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetRegions", "MyController")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { companyId : $('select[name="SelectedCompanyId"]').val()
}).done(function(response) {
    // "response" has the returned data, use it here
}).fail(function(response) {
    // There was an error, handle it here
});
```

That (or something quite similar to it) should fetch the regions from the server.  (Note that I used a little bit of server-side code here just to define the URL.)

The fourth step then takes place in that `done` handler for the AJAX call, where you use the data in the response to create your HTML elements.  Again, I'm going to be mostly guessing on the structure of your objects.  You'll likely want to examine the actual JSON response manually in your browser's debugging tools to make sure it's what you expect.

If `response` is successfully a collection of regions, then using it might look something like this:

```
$('#regionSelection').html('');
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    $('#regionSelection').append('<input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRegionNames" value="' + response[i].Name + '" checked="false" class="checkbox-inline" />');
    $('#regionSelection').append('<label class="control-label">' + response[i].Name + '</label>');
}
```

As you can see, first I empty whatever are the current contents of the `span` (to delete any region checkboxes which were previously added to it.  Then all I'm doing is appending the HTML elements to the `span` manually where the code in the question is appending them during the initial page render.

I can't 100% guarantee that this is a copy/paste solution for your needs, since I don't really know your model structure or your UX or use case for this functionality.  But in terms of dynamically fetching a list of objects from the server to drive the client-side UI, this would do the trick.

Comment: Pure gold! Extra points for breaking into functional steps and explaining each along with code. Super job!

Comment: I added a generic 'Choose one...' entry to the Company List. If this page is re-rendered, say by the controller detecting  unacceptable user input, how can I detect that the Company List has something other than 'Choose One...' selected?  I need to do that so I can put the check boxes for the selected company on the page.  Not sure what to hook.

Comment: @davecove: What causes the page to re-render?  If it's a form post, presumably that selection is one of the values being posted?  If that's the case then you'd have that value server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Filter on the server (send the form back and return just the right items)

   - User may copy the URL and share a filtered view via E-Mail
   - Slower response time of your site. The postback takes time, especially on a mobile connection
   - Good for large amount of choices
2. Filter on the client (send everything the first time and show/hide items)

   - The URL stays the same (if you're not doing something special)
   - Faster response time
   - Good for small and medium amount of options

Alternative one can be done with a appropriate ViewModel:

```
public class FilteredRegions
{
    public FilteredRegions()
    {
        Regions = new List<Region>();
    }

    public int SelectedCompanyID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyList { get; set; }

    public int SelectedRegionID { get; set; }       
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Regions { get; set; }
}
```

Alternative two (which I'd **recommend**, based on the assumption that you've got less than 1000 regions)

Put every region in the view, with a nice data attribute on it:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.Label("Assign the user to one or more regions", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <span class=" col-md-10">
        @foreach (var item in Model.RegionsList)
        {
            <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRegionNames" value="@item.Value" checked="@item.Selected" class="checkbox-inline hide" data-company="@item.CompanyId" />
            @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
        }
    </span>
</div>
```

And than attach an event handle to the dropdown menu, to do something like this: (NOT TESTED)

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
    var companyID = $(this).value;
    $('input[data-company]').hide();
    $('input[data-company="' + companyID + '"]').show();
})
```

i.e. when the company selection changes, hide all the checkboxes and show all the right ones.
You need jquery for the snippet.

Comment: I like the concept here: but I get this error when I add the 'data-company="@item.CompanyId bit : 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a definition for 'CompanyId'. I tried extending SelectListItem to include CompanyId as SelectListItemWithComapnyId, but the DropDownListFor doesn't know to use it so it doesn't see my addition.  Also, How does the script know which control to watch for .change on?